# Pumping lemma for CFL language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

Let $L$={ $\alpha$ in {$a,b$}* | $\alpha$ has exactly two symbols b } .Prove that $L'$ = { $\alpha^n$ | $\alpha$ in $L$ ,$n \ge$0} is not context-free.I was thinking to prove it that way: Since $a^nba^nba^n$ is in $L$ then $a^{n^2}b^na^{n^2}b^na^{n^2}$ is in $L'$.Now I will use the pumping lemma for the language $L'$  .Is my approach for proving that is not CFL right?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: "Since ... is in L then using the pumping lemma for the language L′ I will prove that ..." -- that is not even an English sentence, let alone a proof. *How* do you use the pumping lemma? And what will you prove?

Comment: @Raphael Hello,I have edited the post,thanks for pointing out.

Comment: How is $a^{n^2}b^na^{n^2}b^na^{n^2}\in L'$?  Is $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$?